# Find the number modulo

Tags: java, math, numbers

I have a question. I need to solve this problem: **3 ^ 54 mod 17 =?** (3 to 54 degrees modulo 17 - which will be equal to?). Just please write with the maximum explanation. How did you find this huge number **3 ^ 54**, how to get the module. Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3+%5E+54+mod+17 :p More seriously you should look into [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) Also note that there is a built-in method, see https://ideone.com/fVo2DC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this two equivalent equations:

> c mod m = (a ⋅ b) mod m
>
> c mod m = [(a mod m) ⋅ (b mod m)] mod m

Knowing this you can compute 3 ^ 54 mod 17 very efficient:

```
 3 ^ 54 mod 17 =
 3 ^ 27 * 3 ^ 27 mod 17 =
 (3 ^ 27 mod 17 * 3 ^ 27 mod 17) mod 17 =
 ...
```

Know we can calc the modulo very fast. But how can we divide c fast?

This can be handled by the idea of "Exponentiation by squaring".

```
x^n = x(x^2)^((n-1)/2) if n is odd 
x^n = (x^2)^(n/2) if n is even
```

An algorithm that uses this techniques is called "Fast modular exponentiation"

```
int power(int x, int y, int p){
int res = 1;  
x = x % p;  
  while (y > 0){
      if (y % 2 == 0)
          res = (res*x) % p;
      y /= 2;
      x = (x*x) % p;  
  }
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We know that 3 and 17 are coprime (indeed, both are prime, but that's not required). Because of this, we know that 3 is a generate w.r.t. multiplication for the group of integers modulo 17. That is, for any value `b` between 1 and 16, inclusive, there is some `a` such that `3^a = b (mod 17)`. The only way that is possible is if `3^a` gives unique values modulo 17 at least 16 times in a row (for 3^0, 3^1, ..., 3^15). Thus, it turns out that `3^16 = 1 (mod 17)` and, generally, `a^(b-1) = 1 (mod b)` whenever `a` and `b` are coprime.

This observation will get you down to something with an exponent less than your modulus minus one. Again, it requires that the base and the modulus be coprime, but it's the case in your question and it is a case of interest typically speaking.

More generally, you can always just try multiplying the base by itself a number of times no greater than the modulus and you are bound to find a cycle. Determine the cycle length and offset in the cycle (if any) and you can work out something a lot like what we did above. For instance, if we have `2^103 = ? (mod 10)`, what can we do? We see `2, 2*2 = 4, 2*2*2 = 8, 2*2*2*2 = 16 = 6 (mod 10), 2*2*2*2*2 = 32 = 2 (mod 10`; we have already hit a cycle so we know this repeats forever. Since `2^5 = 2^1 (mod 10)`, we can rewrite `2^103` as `(2^5)^20 * 2^3 = 2^20 * 2^3 = (2^5)^4 * 2^3 = 2^4 * 2^ = 2^7 = 2^5 * 2^2 = 2 * 2^2 = 2^3 (mod 10)`, thus 8.

Finally, if you find a `0` as you're doing the above, just stop; the answer will be zero forever after. For instance, `2^102938210 = ??? (mod 8)` has the answer `0` since we get `2^1 = 2, 2^2 = 4, 2^3 = 8 = 0 (mod 8)`.